# Integrate Scrapy/Twisted event loop in PyQt4 Main loop

Tags: pyqt, twisted, scrapy, event-loop

I am developing a PyQt4 tool which is using scrapy for crawling a website. I start a new process[multiprocessing] to run the Scrapy spider from ui. Everything works fine ~ ui is blocking and Scrapy is scraping.

I would like to have a non blocking ui, though I want to integrate the Twisted event loop  in the PyQt main loop.

Does anyone know how to achieve this as simple as possible?
I am new to Scrapy / PyQt / Multiprocessing / Twisted.

I am on a Xubuntu 12.04 box with PyQt4, Python 2.7 and  Scrapy 0.12.0.2546.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted reactor integrates easily with qt reactor:
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/QTReactor