# QT4Reactor / Scrapy / PyQt4

Tags: pyqt4, scrapy, qeventloop

**How to use Qt4Reactor the right way?**

I have a PyQt4 Application running Scrapy to parse a website and show the results in the ui.

When the user clicks a button, the scraper gets started in another process. The ui blocks and the scraper is running. When the scraper is finished, the data is shown in the ui. What I want is a non-blockung ui when Scrapy is running.

Since Scrapy is build on top of twisted, I have to use a new **process** instead of a **thread** to start it from the ui.

**My question is how to achieve a non-blocking ui as simple as possible?**

I tried to use Qt4Reactor like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    import qt4reactor
    qt4reactor.install()

    MainWindow = DiscogsRenamer()
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    reactor.runReturn()
```

This results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/f/work/py/discogs_renamer/main.py", line 224, in <module>
        qt4reactor.install()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt4reactor.py", line 338, in posixinstall
        installReactor(p)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/main.py", line 32, in installReactor
        raise error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError("reactor already installed")
twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError: reactor already installed
```

I posted another question to this topic:
[Integrate Scrapy/Twisted event loop in PyQt4 Main loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042784/integrate-scrapy-twisted-event-loop-in-pyqt4-main-loop)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must import and install() the qt4reactor **before** importing `twisted.internet.reactor`.

```
import qt4reactor
qt4reactor.install()
from twisted.internet import reactor
```